# How to get the value from hidden or display:none input with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have these two hidden inputs and I want to get the value of both but when trying to access to the values I'm gettin' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```js
// I have been trying from code and chrome console with

console.log(document.getElementById('totalU').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('totalU'));
console.log(document.getElementById('totalW').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('totalW'));
```

```html
<li style="background-color:white"><span>&nbsp;<input id="totalU" type="text" value="18" style="display:none"></span></li>
<li style="background-color:white"><span>&nbsp;<input id="totalW" type="hidden" value="20"></span></li>
```

But still gettin' the null, is there anything wrong with the HTML and javascript? 
Per requirement, I need to use javascript, not jQuery. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Works fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wey60nxc/. Have you checked the browser's console for errors?

Comment: The  first and the third lines are working, providing the elements exist at the time you're retireving the value. Also, the value of an input can never be `null`.

Comment: `display: none` and `type="hidden"` only hide the element from the user. The element is still there.

Comment: I formatted and added your code as a snippet, Run it works fine

Comment: I receive in console Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:49 that's it, just odd

Comment: Where have you put your js code, Put them after the li tags just before closing `</body>` tag

Comment: Plus whoever down voted this, please point out whats wrong with the question? o.O

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy The issue is unable to be reproduced. I downvoted because there is no minimal verifiable example

Comment: @chevybow Thanks at least now he knows why he get downvoted :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('totalU').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('totalU'));
console.log(document.getElementById('totalW').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('totalW'));
```

```html
<li style="background-color:white"><span>&nbsp;<input id="totalU" type="text" value="18" style="display:none"></span></li>
<li style="background-color:white"><span>&nbsp;<input id="totalW" type="hidden" value="20"></span></li>
```

I'm sure you're just running the javascript part before the elements are created.

Check if your `<script>` tag is after this HTML code. Usually they're put before the closing of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Even I'm running from the chrome console the script to get the values, all the page has been loaded but still gettin' the error for null

Comment: Is this by any chance inside an iframe?

Comment: Well, yes, seems to be a problem with the frames in the page, I need to take first the iframe and start from there to get the elements. Thanks.